# Azure Device registration table with tag

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I am exploring push notification with Azure Mobile service using push notification hub for Android platform. I am able to generate the notification using hub for android device. However I want to know about the table which contains the record of device registration with their platform and tags by which they are registered. please help me to find out above table and how to query with that table.

Task I want here to achieve is to find list of all tags that is associated with a device or device which is registered with a particular tag.

Answer (score 0):

Device registrations are maintained by Notification Hubs & querying (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn743807.aspx) it should get the required information